# MongoDB lookup pipeline with multiple conditions does not filter

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections:

Telemetry:

```js
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    name: "ack",
    commandId: 3,
    params: [],
    groundTime: Date(...)
},
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    name: "ack",
    params: [{ name: "commandId", value: 3 }],
    groundTime: Date(...)
},
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 4,
        serviceSubType: 5,
    },
    name: "other",
    params: [3],
    groundTime: Date(...)
}
```

Telecommands:

```js
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    commandId: 3,
    params: [],
    sentTime: Date(...)
},
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    commandId: 4,
    params: [],
    sentTime: Date(...)
}
```

I want to perform a lookup on the `Telecommands` collection: For every document, get the documents from `Telemetry` that:

1. Their `name` field is equal to "ack"
2. They have a `commandId` field, and it matches the `commandId` on the original document
   ***or***
   has a subdocument in the `params` array with a `name` field which is equal to "commandId" and a `value` field which is equal to the `commandId` field in the original document.

Then put those in an "acks" array:

```js
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    commandId: 3,
    params: [],
    sentTime: Date(...),
    acks: [{
                key: {
                    serviceType: 3,
                    serviceSubType: 4,
                },
                name: "ack",
                commandId: 3,
                params: [],
                groundTime: Date(...)
            },
            {
                key: {
                    serviceType: 3,
                    serviceSubType: 4,
                },
                name: "ack",
                params: [{ name: "commandId", value: 3 }],
                groundTime: Date(...)
            }]
},
{
    key: {
        serviceType: 3,
        serviceSubType: 4,
    },
    commandId: 4,
    params: [],
    sentTime: Date(...),
    acks: []
}
```

But I can't get this done.

I tried:

```js
$lookup: {
    from: "Telemetry",
    let: {
        commandId: "$telCommandId",
    },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                name: "ack",
                $expr: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            $eq: [
                                "$$commandId",
                                "$telCommandId"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            params: {
                                name: "commandId",
                                value: "$$commandId"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    as: "acks"
}
```

But it does not filter properly the documents.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all [$lookup's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) `let` parameter has format

```
let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
```

Where `var_1`...`var_n` are names to be used within the pipeline parameter and `expression` calculates value for each name respectively.

Your

```
let: {
    commandId: "$telCommandId",
},
```

assigns value of `document.telCommandId` to a pipeline variable called `$$commandId`. It is always `null` at least for the documents you provided as an example since there are no such field there.

It should be other way round:

```
let: {
    telCommandId: "$commandId",
},
```

so that `$$telCommandId` will be either 3 or 4 depending on value of `document.commandId` in corresponding document in Telecommands collection.

Of course all `$$commandId` in your pipeline needs to be change to `$$telCommandId` to match names in the `let` statement.

Next, when you test

```
                    {
                        params: {
                            name: "commandId",
                            value: "$$commandId"
                        }
                    }
```

you are filtering documents where `document.params` is equal to

```
{
    name: "commandId",
    value: "$$commandId"
}
```

literally. It matches nothing since there is no subdocuments with value equal to the string "$$commandId".

You need to use the same [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) matcher you used to compare commandId to telCommandId. The only difference is that for array you have to use something similar to [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to compare both `name` and `value` of the same element.

The equivalent of $elemMatch in aggregation can be a combination of [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
    {
      $gt: [
        {
          $size: {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$params",
              "as": "p",
              "cond": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$p.name",
                      "commandId"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$p.value",
                      "$$telCommandId"
                    ]
                  },
                  
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        0
      ]
    }
```